# Vagrant: Não sincroniza pasta

Tags: windows, vagrant, linux

Estou usando:

```
Windows 10 64bits
Vagrant 1.9.7
VirtualBox 5.1.22
Box Debian Jessie 64bits
Plugins Vagrant:
  >vagrant-vbguest
  >vagrant-share
```

Minha configuração do *Vagrantfile*:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"

end
```

Entro na pasta do vagrant no sistema virtualizado (*`cd /vagrant`*), dou *`ls`* e ele lista o *`Vagrantfile`*, mas quando crio uma pasta (no caso, quero usar o Jekyll, e uso o comando: *`jekyll new my-awesome-site`*), a pasta é criada, e quando eu dou o comando *`ls`* o sistema lista a pasta juntamente com o *`Vagrantfile`*, mas não aparece no meu sistema a pasta, dou um *`vagrant reload`* mas mesmo assim não funciona (não aparece a pasta no meu sistema, e some ainda, depois de reiniciar o sistema).

Já testei as boxes: *`ubuntu/trusty64`*, *`hashicorp/precise64`*, *`hashicorp/precise32`*. Mas nada.

E só depois de que tentei essas outras boxes que eu instalei os plugins para ver se resolvia alguma coisa, mas mesmo assim nada.

Como posso resolver?

*Lembrando que isso ocorre apenas quando eu crio um arquivo/pasta no sistema virtualizado (debian no caso), mas não o contrario. Quando eu crio uma pasta no windows e inicio/reinicio o sistema, ele aparece na pasta *`/vagrant`* do sistema virtualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando as configurações desse repositório no GitHub: https://github.com/jsturtevant/jekyll-vagrant

Comment: Mas não consegui encontrar o motivo de ter dado certo..